# How to set system variable value in Octopus Deploy from PowerShell

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am trying to assign value to built-in release notes variable in "Run a Script" step.

```
$OctopusParameters["Octopus.Release.Notes"] = "Some release notes"
```

In the next step "Send an Email" I am using this variable in email body, but unfortunately it is empty.

```
<p>#{Octopus.Release.Notes}</p>
```

Is it possible to set Octopus Deploy system variable value from PowerShell and use it in the next step?

I am using Octopus Deploy 3.7.11.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried the cmdlet `Set-OctopusVariable` and it did not work.

```
Set-OctopusVariable -name "Octopus.Release.Notes" -value "Something"
```

Comment: How is this related to my question? I am asking how to set variable in Octopus Deploy not the environment variable in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to overwrite values of the built-in variables provided by Octopus Deploy. But you could define your own output variable and refer to that in the following steps. For example in your 'Run a script'-step use:

```
Set-OctopusVariable -name "MyReleaseNote" -value "Some text here"
```

Then the "Send an Email"-step can refer to this text by using the following (assuming the first step is called 'FirstStep'):

```
#{Octopus.Action[FirstStep].Output.MyReleaseNote}
```

The variable can also be used from a script in other steps, then use the syntax:

```
$relnote = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action[FirstStep].Output.MyReleaseNote"]
```

(If you want to save the generated releasenote perhaps you could save it as an '[artifact](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Artifacts)' in the project).

Comment: Yes, I have already done like this and it works. My initial idea was to populate built-in release notes variable so that release notes are displayed in the specific release.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using Octoposh. Modifying an existing variable is covered in the Octoposh wiki at [Modifying Variables - Edit a variable of a Project/Library variable set](https://github.com/Dalmirog/OctoPosh/wiki/Modifying-Resources#edit-a-variable-of-a-projectlibrary-variable-set).

I wasn't able to get this to work because of timeouts on our network, but it looks like it should work - just not as straight-forward as I expected.