# Setting builtin Octopus variables

Tags: powershell, azure, deployment, azure-cloud-services, octopus-deploy

I am trying to update the value of "Octopus.Action.Azure.CloudServicePackageExtractionDisabled" Octopus variable in deploy.ps1 of cloud-service deployment octopus step. But the following does not seem to work. Any suggestions ?

```
$cloudServicePackageExtractionDisabledpre = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action.Azure.CloudServicePackageExtractionDisabled"]    
Write-Host "PRE CloudServicePackageExtractionDisabled: $cloudServicePackageExtractionDisabledpre"

Set-OctopusVariable -name "Octopus.Action.Azure.CloudServicePackageExtractionDisabled" -value "True"

$cloudServicePackageExtractionDisabledpost = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action.Azure.CloudServicePackageExtractionDisabled"]    
Write-Host "POST CloudServicePackageExtractionDisabled: $cloudServicePackageExtractionDisabledpost"
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: No error. It just prints its default value which is "False" in the POST Write-Host.

Comment: try `-value $true`?

Comment: -value $true does not make any difference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set system variable value in Octopus Deploy from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607706/how-to-set-system-variable-value-in-octopus-deploy-from-powershell)